# click distance with mouse pointer

Tags: c#, mouse, offset

I wanted to make the grid area larger with the PointFromGrid function in the geometry script..
but when i want to enlarge the grid size mouse pointer does not hover over select prefab
how can i fix this as i want?

edit; When I set it to a smaller grid size with the GridFromPoint function, there is no problem, but
when enlarged it does not align properly.

```
 public class Geometry {  

 static public Vector3 PointFromGrid(Vector2Int gridPoint)
 {
    float x = -4.5f + 1.5f * gridPoint.x;
    float z = -4.5f + 1.5f * gridPoint.y;
    return new Vector3(x, 0, z);
 }

 static public Vector2Int GridPoint(int col, int row)
 {
    return new Vector2Int(col, row);
 }

 static public Vector2Int GridFromPoint(Vector3 point)
 {
    int col = Mathf.FloorToInt(4.0f + point.x);
    int row = Mathf.FloorToInt(4.0f + point.z); 
    return new Vector2Int(col, row);
 }
```

this is the selection prefab script

```
 void Start()
 {       
    Vector2Int gridPoint = Geometry.GridPoint(0, 0);
    Vector3 point = Geometry.PointFromGrid(gridPoint);
    tileHighlight = Instantiate(tileHighlightPrefab, point, Quaternion.identity, gameObject.transform);
    tileHighlight.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{        
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {           
        Vector3 point = hit.point;
        Vector2Int gridPoint = Geometry.GridFromPoint(point);            

        tileHighlight.SetActive(true);
        tileHighlight.transform.position = Geometry.PointFromGrid(gridPoint);
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The `Mathf.FloorToInt` might correct deviations in small grids but not in large grids. This could mean that the transformations are also wrong for small grids but that this truncation hides the error.

Comment: what about the solution? @Olivier Jacot-Descombes

Comment: It is really hard to tell what you are calculating. What is -4.5f, 1.5f or 4.0f? Define constants for these magic numbers, so that everyone understands what they represent.

Comment: -4.5f + 1.5f grid size, Align the selection prefab with 4.0f mouse pointer, i.e. deviation occurs as shown in the pictures @Olivier Jacot-Descombes

Answer (score 1):

`GridFromPoint` seems not to be consistent with `PointFromGrid`. Assuming that these two methods perform the reverse operation of each other and also assuming that `PointFromGrid` is correct, then
`GridFromPoint` should calculate:

```
int col = Mathf.FloorToInt((point.x + 4.5f) / 1.5f);
int row = Mathf.FloorToInt((point.z + 4.5f) / 1.5f);
```

This is a simple algebraic tranformation. Given (`PointFromGrid`):

```
x = -4.5 + (1.5 * grid.x)
```

solve for `grid.x`:

```
(0)                    x               = -4.5 + (1.5 * grid.x)
(1) add 4.5:           x + 4.5         =         1.5 * grid.x
(2) divide by 1.5:     (x + 4.5) / 1.5 =               grid.x
(3) swap sides:        grid.x          = (x + 4.5) / 1.5
```

The same transformation applies for `z`.

---

In a comment you say that -4.5f + 1.5f is grid size and 4.0f an align parameter. It is important to know what these numbers represent to be able to do the transormation right. `1.5f` must be the row height and column width of your grid, where as `-4.5f` is an offset between the origin of the grid and (probably) world coordinates (or possibly some shape coordinates). `4.0f` seems to make no sense, as the reverse operation must use the same offset and grid size.

Comment: Thank you very very much, it works as I want it this way :)) @Olivier Jacot-Descombes

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> float x = -4.5f + 1.5f * gridPoint.x;
> float z = -4.5f + 1.5f * gridPoint.y;
> ```

When you perform arithmetic or multiplication/division in the same statement, something the compiler, might *misunderstand* what you want to do.

Consider using parenthesis when performing single-line mathematics that involve different kinds of operations.

When you use parenthesis you prevent the compiler from seeing this:

```cs
float x = -4.5f + 1.5f * gridPoint.x;
```

and and **assuming** you mean this:

```cs
float x = (-4.5f + 1.5f) * gridPoint.x;
```

When most likely you want it to work like

```cs
float x = -4.5f + (1.5f * gridPoint.x);
```

Without explicitly telling the compiler which one to interpret, it will sometimes pick the wrong one and you get weird things happening with offset values.

Comment: thanks for the comment but this doesn't fix the problem